# Get exit code from subprocess.check_output

Tags: python

How can I get the exit code of `subprocess.check_output`?
I'm assuming the returncode should be `0` if a file is found matching my pattern and non-zero if no files are found matching the pattern?
If there is an exception, I'm recieving a non-zero returncode, as expected.

```
try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(["staf", "server.com", "PROCESS", "START", "SHELL", "COMMAND", "ls *heapdump*", "WAIT", "RETURNSTDOUT", "STDERRTOSTDOUT"])
        print result
except CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.returncode)
        sys.exit(e.returncode)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) says:

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The
>   CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode
>   attribute and any output in the output attribute.

So, if you don't end up in your `except` block, you can assume 0 was returned. You're already doing the right thing to handle non-zero return codes.

Comment: is there an alternative to `subprocess.check_output`, which would return `non-zero` if file is not found and `0` if file is found? Similiar to the way bash would operate.

Comment: Do you care about the output of the subprocess? If not, you can use `subprocess.call`. If you do, you need to use `p = subprocess.Popen(...,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, and then check `p.returncode` after the process is done.